# MySQL - How do I relate a custom table bi-directionally with user and usermeta tables? - Wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join, sql-view

I am using Wordpress, PhpMyAdmin, MySQL.
I am also quite novice when it comes to SQL and databases, so bear with me.

I have a Custom Data Table *(this is a master table of user information)*, which I want to relate bi-directionally with the wp_users and wp_usermeta tables - meaning if a user updates their profile (Users or Usermeta tables) then the Custom Data Table would automatically update without me needing to manually input their updated information.

Likewise, if I edit the Custom Data Table I want the related information in Users and Usermeta to automatically update.

I tried creating a rough diagram of what is in my head. [Diagram of data handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBVov.jpg)

The current system is terrible and very difficult to maintain. Another issue is that there are many SQL reports that use the current Custom Data Table. I understand that the solution I am looking for most likely means creating a completely new table. That's ok.

```
       User
–––––––––––––––––––
| ID  | username  |
|–––––+–––––––––––|
| 376 | John      |
| 377 | Paul      |
| 378 | Ringo     |
–––––––––––––––––––

       Usermeta
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| meta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
|–––––––––+–––––––––+––––––––––+––––––––––––|
| 8       | 1       | job      | Keys       |
| 102     | 2       | job      | Vocals     |
| 203     | 3       | job      | Drums      |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

       Custom_Table
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
| ID | username  | job     | user_ID |
|––––+–––––––––––+–––––––––+–––––––––|
| 1  | John      | Keys    | 376     |
| 2  | Paul      | Vocals  | 377     |
| 3  | Ringo     | Drums   | 378     |
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Basically, this is what I have a query *(except I have many more lines of the usermeta)*:

```
CREATE TABLE custom_table
    SELECT users.username,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'job' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS job,
    users.ID
    FROM wp_users as users, wp_usermeta as umeta
    WHERE umeta.user_id = users.ID
```

This creates the table I want but if any of the tables are updated it is not 'synced' anywhere else. Is this possible? Would it be done by some sort of trigger (I am still unfamiliar with triggers)?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a view instead of a table. This gives you an always up-to-date perspective at your actual data, without any maintenance cost (and, for what it worth, without storage cost either).

```
create view custom_view as 
select 
    u.username, 
    um.meta_value as job
    u.id as user_id
from wp_users as users u
left join wp_usermeta as umeta um on um.user_id = u.ID and um.meta_key = 'job'
```

Note about your original query:

- it is actually invalid SQL (it was missing a `group by` clause)
- event if it had a `group by` clause, it would filter out users without a job (which might not be what you want)
- do not use old-school, implicit joins; always use standard joins (with the `on` keyword and no comma in the `from` clause)

Since you are interested in only one meta key per user, the query can be rewritten as a simple `join`, without aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Yes, sorry, I left out the group by. 
At the end I have
`code` GROUP BY users.ID
`code` ORDER BY users.ID

The single meta-key per user was just for the example. What I am working with will need around 26 meta-keys.

I have also tried creating a View but phpmyadmin always stalled and froze when I tried to see the view or run anything against it. Could that be a server issue? Because of this I haven't been able to explore what Views could do for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Updateable `VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html) to solve this:

```
CREATE VIEW custom AS
  SELECT User.ID, User.username,
    CASE WHEN meta_key = 'job' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END AS job
  FROM User INNER JOIN Usermeta ON Usermeta.user_id = User.ID
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3f3f4f6b73a18394e8dae338a977759)

> For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable.

In case you need one of the constructs you can only [create the `VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) and have to update the source tables itself. The view is always synced with the source tables.

Comment: Thank you for the demo! Helps to see it in action.

For some reason when I create a View PhpMyAdmin freezes and I have to refresh and delete the view. Could it be a server issue? In my table/view there need to be over 2,000 users and around 28-30 columns of data for each.